# How to plot many kdeplots on one figure in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data

```
name        val
G.Kittle    4.0
G.Kittle    10.0
D.Hopkins   3.0
L.Fitzgerald    6.0
... ...
C.Kupp  18.0
R.Woods 21.0
N.Harry 7.0
S.Michel    -6.0
```

Each `name` has many values, and I would like to plot a distribution for each name on the same figure. I tried doing this using the `hue` argument, but that messed everything up and treated all distributions as having an area of 1 together, however, I want each distribution to be independent from each other and have their own area of 1. Does that make sense? I would also like all of them to be gray, which `hue` doesn't allow naturally.

Edit: Also, when I use `hue`, I get this error `UserWarning: Dataset has 0 variance; skipping density estimate.`

Comment: I still get warning `UserWarning: Dataset has 0 variance; skipping density estimate`, and the distributions look wonky (different than if I were to just plot a single distribution independently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sns.kdeplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) has a parameter `common_norm=` which default to `True`. In that case, the kde curves will be scaled proportionally to the number of values such that the total area sums to 1. Setting `common_norm=False` shows all the kde curves such that each individually has an area of one.

Note that there also is a `multiple=` parameter, defaulting to `“layer”`, but which also can be set to `“stack”` or `“fill”`. In that case the common norm would be appropriate.

The curves can all be colored grey providing a palette as a list of colors with 'grey'. The length of the list should be the same as the number of hue values. As all hue values are the same, a legend would look strange. The legend can be suppressed with `legend=False`.

When a hue value only appears in one row, the kdeplot with one element isn't drawn, but shows the warning `Dataset has 0 variance; skipping density estimate`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.random.choice([*'ABCD'], 100, p=[0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]),
                   'val': np.random.rand(100).cumsum()})
df.loc[0, 'name'] = 'E'  # exactly one row with name 'E'
df['name'] = df['name'].astype('category')
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='val', hue='name', palette=['grey'] * len(df['name'].cat.categories),
            common_norm=False, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Awesome! Why doesn't `alpha` work here, though? I would like to change the alpha for these kdeplots. @JohanC

Comment: You can use `'lightgrey'` for a lighter shade of grey.  `alpha` seems to only affect the fill color.